# Translation of "let me know"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

I use the phrase "let me know" all the time in English. For example:

- Just let me know when you're free.
- Could you let me know whether you can come tomorrow?
- If you have any questions, just let me know.
- Let me know what you think.
- etc.

What options are there in Spanish for expressing "let me know," and how are they normally used?

Comment: "let me know" usually means "tell me", so I would translate it as "dime" or "avisame" in most contexts.

Comment: @Filmzy yeah you're right, though "házmelo saber" is also a common for it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general it could be translated as either `avísame` or `házmelo saber.` For example:

- Just let me know when you're free. --> `Avísame cuando estés libre`.
- Could you let me know whether you can come tomorrow? --> `¿Me podrías avisar si puedes venir mañana?`
- If you have any questions, just let me know. --> `Si tienes alguna pregunta, házmelo saber` or... `avísame si tienes alguna pregunta` or... `si tienes alguna pregunta, avísame`.
- Let me know what you think. --> `Hazme saber qué opinas` or... `avísame qué opinas`.

Personally, I prefer `avísame`. It's more concise.

Comment: ¿Podría usted decirme cuál es la forma plural de "házmelo"?

Comment: @Phoenix `Háznoslo`. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

I must agree that `avísame` is more concise, but at the same time I think it's too imperative. What I mean is that it could be seen as rude since you are giving an order. I would use `podrías avisarme` instead because it's more passive. It's the exact same difference that exists between `Tell me this` and `Could you tell me this?`.